# Downloading an Excel Spreadsheet through the Browser Results in Unwanted Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel

I have a .NET application that allows users to download a report as a .xls. The application can be run in both IE11 and Chrome. Upon clicking the "download" button, the .xls file is saved to the user's download directory. It is then opened in Excel 2010 or higher. However, upon opening, users are prompted with the following message:

[image]

The code for the downloading of the Excel (in JavaScript) is as follows:

```
function exportToExcel() 
{
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Report1</x:Name>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
    tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";   

    // This is a copy of the original HTML before we modify it for the Excel report:
    var orig = $('#TransactionsResultTable').html();

    // Remove all hyperlinks and their associated attributes from the table for the Excel export:
    $('#TransactionsResultTable a').removeAttr('href');
    var mod = $('#TransactionsResultTable').html();
    while(mod.indexOf("<a>")>=0)
    {        
        mod = mod.replace("<a>", "");
    }
    while(mod.indexOf("</a>")>=0)
    {
        mod = mod.replace("</a>", "");
    }    
    tab_text = tab_text + mod;


    tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Report.xls');
        }
    } else {
        $('#exportLink').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
        $('#exportLink').attr('download', 'Report.xls');
    }

    // Restore table to its original state(front-end)
    $('#TransactionsResultTable').html(function(){return orig});
}
```

How can I change my code to avoid this prompt altogether?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are sending an HTML table, not an Excel file: Excel detects this and warns the user appropriately.  If you don't want your users to see that warning, then you need to send an actual Excel-formatted file.  Google for "Office extension hardening" if you want more details.

Comment: Generate a real Excel file using a library that knows how to create them, such as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [Aspose.Cells](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net) etc.

Comment: Try sheet.js library